# order of select_related in chain

Tags: python, django

Does the order select_related is put in a queryset chain matter?

i.e. is there any difference between:

```
SomeModel.objects.select_related().all()
```

and

```
SomeModel.objects.all().select_related()
```

In my brief testing they both seem to cache objects but I'm wondering if there are any performance differences or anything else I'm not realizing is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both execute the same exact query. So no, there would be no performance differences.

To test, try this:

```
q = SomeModel.objects.select_related().all()
print q.query

q = SomeModel.objects.all().select_related()
print q.query
```

You should get the same exact query

Comment: Great thanks, do you have any references to back that up?  I believe you I just want to be certain and understand how it all works.

Comment: Great, thanks!  So you could put select_related anywhere in a filter chain as long as you hadn't done anything to force the query to evaluate and it would have the same performance?

Comment: From the few tests I've done, it seems to make no difference where you place `select_related` in the chain.